# What is a better alternative to "at the most"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, phrases

I was typing out an email to my colleague asking him to finish and deliver the current job. This is how it ends:

*If possible please send it today or by tomorrow at the most.*

It just doesn't feel right, especially the *at the most* part. How can I improve this sentence? The email is still in draft and yet to be sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, *at the most* doesn't really fit in this context. Instead you can use "**[at the latest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latest)**".

> the latest acceptable time —usually used in the phrase *at the latest*

So you could rephrase as:

*If possible, please send it today or by tomorrow at the latest.*

Answer (score 0):

When a job/money is due before a certain time, it is called a
[**Deadline**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=deadline%20definition&ie=&oe=)  *"
1. 
the latest time or date by which something should be completed.
"the deadline for submissions is Friday 5th February"
synonyms:
time limit, limit, finishing date, finishing time, target date, target time, cut-off point 
"they stipulated a deadline for the army's withdrawal"*

> You could write;-  "the deadline for the completion of this job is 2pm tomorrow."

Answer (score -1):

Removing *if possible* would make your request stronger, and could eliminate the need for *at the latest.* Be careful doing this if you're writing a superior.

Additionally, you don't need to say *today*. When you say *by tomorrow at the latest* or *no later than tomorrow*, it's understood that receiving it today is acceptable and ideal as well.